# VS2017: multiple asp.net core projects debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

We are migrating our project www.SampleProject.com from VS2013 into VS2017, also considering upgrade into ASP.NET Core. Project has following structure:

- some class library projects (BLL and DAL)
- API (WebAPI2 project)
- UI (asp.net project with NG 1.4 used)

During debug:

- Primary start-up project is UI, starting on localhost:52000
- Second start-up project is API, starting on localhost:52000/API/

Such configuration allows us to debug both projects simultaneously, which is handy.

Also, this separation allows us to deploy API as separate REST API service (api.SampleProject.com) and also use API internally for UI (app.SampleProject.com/api)

In production environment, 'internal API' is configured in IIS as nested application in UI project.

However, this is not working with ASP.NET Core and VS2017.

Is there any known way how to debug two ASP.NET Core projects on same port (as described above)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have both projects listed as Startup projects?

Comment: Indeed. If they are set up on same port, I get an error message: "Access is denied."

Comment: You can't run two programs on the same port. This is not an ASP.net limitation. You need to switch to debugging against IIS (it's probably possible to configure IIS Express but you would have to manually edit the applicationHost.config file)